# Is my function not working because it is inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why my function is not working?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
       $('.side-by-side div').each(function() {
       $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent().find('img'));
    });
});
```

I tried to do it this way as maybe we cant have a function inside a function and it still didn't work:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
     if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
         var $each = $('.side-by-side div').each();
         $(each).insertAfter($(this).parent().find('img'));
        });
    });
```

Please can anyone advise? all what I am trying to do is to run the following function on re-size and on-load when width under 770px!

```
$('.side-by-side div').each(function() {
       $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent().find('img'));
    });
```

Why isn't working with me!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call it on load and on resize. Your code only handles resize.

Try something like this:

```
$(window).on("resize, load", function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
       $('.side-by-side div').each(function() {
           $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent().find('img'));
       });
    }
});
```

If it were my code though I would do this with CSS Media queries.

Comment: Please take a look here: http://loaistudio.com/services it is working now as wanted, but only one thing missing - reset everything back "i.e please resize to small and then resize back to big see what happens?"

Comment: To swap them back you need to have an `else` condition and swap the image with `$(this)`. But seriously, use media queries for this and just float them. You're using them already in your CSS and they can be used for this too.

Comment: You are 100% right! that what I tried to do before! and it worked like magic! but the only problem is I was trying to make the text vertical align to the middle with the image but I just couldn't :(

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax issue. Try this :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
       $('.side-by-side div').each(function() {
           $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent().find('img'));
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: This works on re-size only how to make it work on load as well?

Comment: If it works then Nathan answered your original question and deserves an upvote.

Comment: I am trying to make it work on load as well... take a look here: http://loaistudio.com/services try to re-size

Comment: @Loai Pleased to help you :)

Comment: @NathanP. The thing is I already have $( document ).ready(function() { wrapping all the function, but for some reason it does nothing...

Comment: @Loai I cannot tell without the whole code... But basically, take the sale code as above, replace `resize` by `ready`, and it should work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47989/discussion-between-loai-and-nathan-p)